# How to connect with PostgreSQL database with SSL using certificates and key from client Eclipse in Java

Tags: java, postgresql, ssl, jdbc, ssl-certificate

I am trying to connect with PostgreSQL database from client with SSL enabled on server 10.30.32.186 port 6432 using below java code.

I am using certificates ([server-cert.pem, server-key.pem, ca.cert] and [postgresql.crt, postgresql.pk8, root.crt]).

Is there are any specific java understandable certificate and key file format?

```
package com.ssl;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class DBConnect {

private final String url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.30.32.186:6432/postgres?sslmode=require&sslcert=/root/.postgresql/postgresql.crt&sslkey=/root/.postgresql/postgresql.pk8&sslrootcert=/root/.postgresql/root.crt&sslpassword=postgress";

private final String user = "postgres";
private final String password = "postgres123";

/**
 * Connect to the PostgreSQL database
 *
 * @return a Connection object
 */
public Connection connect() {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        System.out.println("Connected to the PostgreSQL server successfully.");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

    return conn;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    DBConnect db = new DBConnect();
    db.connect();

}
}
```

Gives error:

```
SSL error: -1
```

Code no 2:

```
package SSL_Enablement;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PostgresSSLConnection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        // Set SSL properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "postgres");
        props.setProperty("password", "postgres123");
        props.setProperty("ssl", "true");
        props.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
        props.setProperty("sslmode", "Verify-CA");
        props.setProperty("sslcert", "/root/.postgresql/server-cert.pem");
        props.setProperty("sslkey", "/root/.postgresql/server-key.pem");
        props.setProperty("sslrootcert", "/root/.postgresql/ca.cert");

        // Initialize SSL context
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.30.32.186:6432/postgres";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        System.out.println("Connected DB using SSL");
        // Use the connection...
        // ...

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Gives error:

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Could not read SSL key file /root/.postgresql/server-key.pem.
  at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:284)
  at sun.security.ssl.AbstractKeyManagerWrapper.getPrivateKey(SSLContextImpl.java:1552)
  at sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createClientPossession(X509Authentication.java:220)
  at sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:175)
  at sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:88)
  at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.choosePossession(CertificateMessage.java:1080)
  at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1101)
  at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:958)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:421)
  at sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.onConsumeFinished(Finished.java:989)
  at sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.consume(Finished.java:852)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
  at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
  at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
  at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
  at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:584)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168)
  at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
  at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
  at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247)
  at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
  at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
  at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
  at SSL_Enablement.PostgresSSLConnection.main(PostgresSSLConnection.java:26)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: extra data given to DerValue constructor
  at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:423)
  at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:306)
  at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:347)
  at sun.security.util.DerValue.wrap(DerValue.java:334)
  at sun.security.util.DerValue.wrap(DerValue.java:319)
  at javax.crypto.EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.<init>(EncryptedPrivateKeyInfo.java:84)
  at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.getPrivateKey(LazyKeyManager.java:236)
  ... 29 more
```

Code no 3:

```
package SSL_Enablement;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class PostgresSSLConnection {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Connection conn = null;
    try {
        // Set SSL properties
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.setProperty("user", "postgres");
        props.setProperty("password", "postgres123");
        props.setProperty("ssl", "true");
        props.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");
        props.setProperty("sslmode", "Verify-CA");
        props.setProperty("sslcert", "/root/.postgresql/postgresql.crt");
        props.setProperty("sslkey", "/root/.postgresql/postgresql.pk8");
        props.setProperty("sslrootcert", "/root/.postgresql/root.crt");

        // Initialize SSL context
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:postgresql://10.30.32.186:6432/postgres";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, props);
        System.out.println("Connected DB using SSL");
        // Use the connection...
        // ...

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Gives error:

```
    org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: -1
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:584)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:247)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:434)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:291)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at SSL_Enablement.PostgresSSLConnection.main(PostgresSSLConnection.java:26)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: -1
    at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:133)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:331)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:274)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:269)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1568)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:446)
    at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1
    at org.postgresql.ssl.LazyKeyManager.chooseClientAlias(LazyKeyManager.java:105)
    at sun.security.ssl.AbstractKeyManagerWrapper.chooseClientAlias(SSLContextImpl.java:1531)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createClientPossession(X509Authentication.java:200)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication$X509PossessionGenerator.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:175)
    at sun.security.ssl.X509Authentication.createPossession(X509Authentication.java:88)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.choosePossession(CertificateMessage.java:1080)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.onProduceCertificate(CertificateMessage.java:1101)
    at sun.security.ssl.CertificateMessage$T13CertificateProducer.produce(CertificateMessage.java:958)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.produce(SSLHandshake.java:421)
    at sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.onConsumeFinished(Finished.java:989)
    at sun.security.ssl.Finished$T13FinishedConsumer.consume(Finished.java:852)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(SSLHandshake.java:377)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:444)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(HandshakeContext.java:422)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:182)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:152)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Does that connection string work with something else, such as `psql`?

Comment: are you running this as the root user?

Comment: @eduyayo I am not a root user. I am running this through a client machine 10.30.32.143 and host is 10.30.32.186 port 6432.

Comment: @jjanes from psql host side we just verified ssl using command - "psql -h 10.30.32.186 -p 6432 -d postgres -U postgres". We didn't try using any string connection.

Comment: Well, try it in psql with the connection string.  Obviously leave off the 'jdbc:' at the start.

Comment: The files are inside the root folder. You may not have permissions on them

Comment: @eduyayo I have changed the permissions as well and tried. Also tried placing those files at another location but that didn't worked.

Comment: @jjanes I am able to connect now. Just changed the extension of key file from PEM to DER and it worked fine. 

So please give answer and write same thing so I can accept your answer.

Comment: @eduyayo  I am able to connect now. Just changed the extension of key file from PEM to DER and it worked fine. So please give answer and write same thing so I can accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The files are inside the root folder. You may not have permissions on them